# How can i write a formula using math symbols input in another cell ? How to use Evaluate?

Tags: worksheet-function

Want to make a table like below, after tons of research, kind get idea I probably need to use evaluate. Just don't know how.
Appreciate any thoughts and help

[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7nk8.jpg)

So A1 will be math symbols '+', '-', '*', ...

B1,C1....A2,A3...row and columns will enter numbers

How can I write formula in B2 to make is calculate B1 + A2

NOTE, I Need formula to take the math symbols from A1 automatically, so if I change A1 from '+' to '-' whole sheet recalculate automatically

Dont know if I described clearly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula way to use **math symbol** and **Evaluate** function :

1] To create **math symbol**

Select `A1` >> Data Validation >>

- Allow : `List`
- Source : `+,-,*,/`
- OK

2] To create **Range Name**

Select `B2` >> Define name >>

- Name : `Eval`
- Refers to : `=EVALUATE($A2&$A$1&B$1)`
- OK

Then,

3] In `B2`, formula copied across and down  :

```
=Eval
```

Finish

Remark :

1. **EVALUATE** is a Macro 4 function, your file need to be saved in **xlsm** type **Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet**
2. To click and select the math symbol from cell A1, so if you change A1 from '**+**' to '**-**' or '*****' or '**/**' whole table will recalculate automatically.

[image]

Comment: This is very cool ! I did not realize Excel4 macros were still supported.

Comment: Worked. Thanks!!

Comment: The article i saw also mentioned something about random numbers.  Show random number in first column and row , like integer between 1-20 . Do you happen to know how?

Comment: In A2 enter : =RANDBETWEEN(1,20) and copied down, then copied the formula to B1 and copied across right.

Comment: Thank you bosco

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined function:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Evalu(a As String, b As String, c As String) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Evalu = Evaluate(a & b & c)
End Function
```

It will treat the second argument as an operator.  In cell **B2** enter:

```
=evalu($A2,$A$1,B$1)
```

and copy both across and downward:

[image]

**NOTE:**

The positions of the **$** in the formula are very important.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Tried in 2007. Doesn't work. Maybe my version too old